# How to extract connected bipartite graph from incidence matrix

Tags: matrix, graphs-and-networks

I'm trying to extract a connected bipartite graph Bconn from the a given incidence matrix B-

I have a matrix representing a bipartite graph - the incidence matrix B (weighted or not is unimportant). I want to extract the incidence matrix Bconn of the corresponding connected bipartite sub-graph. The incidence matrix may be rectangular. ù

One can transform the incidence matrix B into a squared adjacency matrix A, where the off-diagonal blocks are the incidence matrices (one the transpose of the other if the bi-partite graph is undirected and thus A is symmetric) - standard basic graph theory.

I would like to find a method for both directed and undirected graphs, and I do NOT want to transform the incidence into an adjacency matrix and in turn A into a graph, and then use ConnectedComponent or SubGraph, and then re-transform the graph object into a matrix: this method is not very efficient. I think that just working with matrices is faster.

I have been able to find a method for undirected NON-bipartite graph, but probably there is a even more efficient way to solve the problem and especially to find a way so to operate directly with the incidence matrix B.

My code is the following:

```
Sx = Dimensions[B][[1]]; Sy = Dimensions[B][[2]];

A = Join[Join[Table[0, {i, 1, Sx}, {j, 1, Sx}], B, 2],Join[B // Transpose, Table[0, {i, 1, Sy}, {j, 1, Sy}], 2]];

isnode = Position[Total[A], 0] // Reverse;

Aconn = Transpose[Delete[Transpose[Delete[A, isnode]], isnode]];

Bconn = A[[1 ;; Sx, Sy + 1, Sx + Sy]];
```

Of course I can do a function doing all these operations, but the point is that I'm not convinced of this algorithm, as I'm looking to something faster and that I can use directly to B.

Thanks for any suggestion/solution!!

Comment: Would `IncidenceGraph` help? It takes the incidence matrix and converts to a `Graph` object.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau "incidence matrix" has several different and confusing meanings, unfortunately.  I think in Mathematica (`IncidenceMatrix` and `IncidenceGraph`) this matrix describes the connections between edges and vertices: rows are vertices, columns are edges.  Another meaning is when we describe the connections of the two kinds of vertices of a *bipartite* graph: rows are the first group of vertices and columns are the second group.  It sounds like the OP is using the expression in the latter sense.

Comment: @sam84 I am not following your question completely. Why do you want to avoid building an adjacency matrix?  This is the simplest solution: it's as simple as padding your incidence matrix with zeros.  And it doesn't even waste memory if you use sparse arrays.  Given an incidence matrix `mat`, the adjacency matrix will be `am = PadLeft[SparseArray[mat], {1, -1} Total@Dimensions[mat]]`, then use `AdjacencyGraph`.

Comment: Regardless of your preferred graph representation you can do a `BreadthFirstScan`. Starting node is Blue, 1st layer is Red, 2nd layer is Blue, etc. Blue and Red define the bipartite graph.

Comment: @Szabolcs The reason I do not want to work with the adjecency matrix is that I loose information on the nodes I removed so extract the connected graph. Say I have a 10x5 incidence matrix (10 nodes group 1, 5 nodes group 2), I transform it in a 15x15 adjacency matrix. Then I extract the connected part, and I obtain a 12x12 matrix. To which groups the nodes I have removed belong to?

Comment: @sam84 You just need to build your 15 by 15 adjacency matrix so that nodes 1-10 are in one group and nodes 11-15 in the other one.  Then it's very clear which one belongs where.  Work with `Graph`s and use `ConnectedComponents`.  You don't get a 12 by 12 matrix as a result but a list of vertices, and you can easily tell which group they're in by their index.

Comment: Contrary to what you said, working with `Graph`s instead of matrices is not always slower.  It depends on the situation.  Also, some `Graph`-processing functions unfortunately have their quirks which limits performance if you use the default settings but there are fixes for that.  If you have trouble with performance, you can describe it in the question, and show some benchmarks.

Comment: If you really need to work only with matrices, you could do something like this: `k=1; FixedPoint[Unitize[im.(#.im)] &, 
 ReplacePart[ConstantArray[0, Length[im]], k -> 1]]`.  Here `im` is the incidence matrix.  This command will give a vector where 1s indicate nodes from the first group that are connected to node `k`.  You can multiply the result with `im` again to get the nodes in the connected component from the second group.  You can work with the transpose of `im` to start with a node from the second group.